# Selecting bindpose nodes

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I am having issues selecting all of the bindpose nodes in a scene.

How can I get them?

I am using PyMEL for this particular script.

Comment: And the boilerplate question: What have you tried, yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
pm.ls( type = 'dagPose')
```

to get all of the pose nodes in the scene. Then loop through those and check the .bindpose attribute to see if the pose node is a dag pose.

```
all_poses = pm.ls(type = 'dagPose') or []
bind_poses = [k for k in all_poses if k.bindPose.get()]
```